# Vertical scrolling in tablelayout (SDK 14 only)

Tags: android, xml, listview

My ScrollView is working on all Android versions from 4.1 to 4.4 except on 4.0.x.
(My minSdkVersion is 14)

I know that it's a bad idea to put a ListView in a ScrollView but even without the ListView it won't work. (I don't mind that the ListView isn't scrollable.)

So what can I do to make the vertical ScrollView work on Android 4.0?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/info_mainsv" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/info_tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  ...

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView ... />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewDoel"
            style="@style/nowCardStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:clickable="false"
             />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        ...
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```